# R aborted when using ggsave with cairo_pdf

Tags: r, ggplot2, cairo, ggsave

I recently updated R to version 4.1.1 on MacOS via Homebrew. Since then, everytime I tried to use ggsave with the cairo_pdf device like this on R-Studio:

`ggsave(plot = p, filename = plot_file, device = cairo_pdf, width = 8, height = 8)`

R then crashes and issues the following error message: R Session aborted. R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated.

I have checked R capabilities(), it all shows ok as shown below. I have also reinstalled cairo and R from brew but the problem persists. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this? Many thanks

Comment: is your rstudio the latest version?

Comment: yes, it is  1.4.1717. What I have just done is to uninstall R and Rstudio from brew and  to re-install everything but directly from R install package and not via brew. Now it seems to work. Things started to go wrong after a  recent 'brew update'..so maybe something got messed up there. Thanks for your comment.